# Magento 1.9.2 - Save custom admin form product new & edit page (custom tab)

Tags: php, forms, magento, admin, backend

I achieved to add a custom tab / grid to the product new & edit page with an input field inside. Following this [tutorial](http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/custom-tabs-magento-product-admin/)

The problem is that it's **not saving** the data input. And at this point I have no idea if this is actually not covered in the tutorial or I made a mistake.

Is this enough to save the data input?

```
$customFieldValue =  $this->_getRequest()->getPost('custom_field');

$product->save();
```

How could I debug this value in the backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not covered by tutorial. To see the difference you probably have to add [new attribute to product](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=magento%20add%20attribute%20to%20product) and then do something like:

```
$customFieldValue =  $this->_getRequest()->getPost('custom_field');
$product->setNewAttribute($customFieldValue); 
$product->save();
```

Comment: So I have to add an eav attribute with [ 'visible' => false ] and then to store the input value via observer and set method in there?

Comment: Maybe you are overcomplicating things? If you need attribute on separate tab it should be enough to add new attribute group and assign those attributes to new group. You probably don't need all those extra code for new tab in product view. You can do all this in admin panel.

Comment: Yeah I know, but I was just curious to find out how it works for custom input types (since the default magento attribute types don't cover all input forms).

Comment: Ah, I get it now. In such case - I would say yes: Try creating invisible field and save it in the event handler. Good luck.